# Can someone clarify how "taxonomy term ID from URL" works?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I recently set up a View block that displays node titles that share the taxonomy terms (Tag vocabulary) of the node on which the block is displayed. I was unsure how to do this myself, so I found a tutorial. Everyone works fine, but I don't understand why.

The key to setting up this block was to establish a contextual filter with "When the filter value is NOT available" set to provide the default value of Type: "Taxonomy term ID from URL." However, unless I'm mistaken, the View is clearly taking taxonomy terms from the content of the node rather than the URL. It seems to me, according to what I've selected, that the URL would be the source of the terms it's looking for.

Again, the block seems to be functioning exactly the way I want it to (by using the node's tags as contextual filter criteria), but I don't know why using "Taxonomy term ID from URL" makes it work this way. Again, I don't believe there is any information in the URL itself that the View is using.

Can someone help me understand how this is working?

Thank you.

EDIT: Sorry, to clarify, I also have the contextual filter set primarily to "Has taxonomy term ID." But I also don't know how this is pulling information correctly. How does it know to look for the ID under the current node's ID rather than the URL, where I would normally tell it to look for an argument?

Comment: Are you sure you needed to set it? As you suspect, Views probably takes the taxonomy terms via the nodes' context rather than the ID in the URL. The setting is for the case where Views can't get context and requires an external source.

Comment: Queenvictoria--Ah, I think that’s it! So Views automatically knows to look for terms from the node when you set the “Has taxonomy term ID” contextual filter, I guess?

Comment: I'd love to hear an exact explanation of how it works!

Comment: @Dalmaz I think my original question was the result of a misunderstanding of how the view was working in the first place. The "taxonomy term ID from URL," I believe, is actually a backup for the primary functionality of the view, which is working from a basic "Has taxonomy term ID" filter. As stated in the logic, it only uses the URL if there is no value provided from the main filter. So if the node has no taxonomy terms attached to it, THEN it starts looking for terms in the URL.